# breakpoints when transforming an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have recently been getting into a more functional approach to writing javascript. I'm currently trying to figure out how **debugging** should be done in a good way when transforming arrays. To be more precise, how can we use the help of breakpoints? Here is **Example A**:

```
myArray
  .filter(fooFilter)
  .sort(fooSort)
  .map(fooMap)
  .reduce(fooReduce)
```

How would one actually add a breakpoint to this? If the code looked like this instead (more imperative way) **Example B**:

```
const filteredArray = myArray.filter(fooFilter);
const sortedArray = filteredArray.sort(fooSort);
const mappedArray = sortedArray.map(fooMap);
const reducedArray = mappedArray.reduce(fooReduce);
```

Adding breakpoints to the example above would not be a problem.

So I am trying to ask if it is possible to somehow modify **Example A** to somehow support easier breakpoints? Also, how should one think when it comes to debugging when writing according to the functional paradigm?

**Edit 1:**

I am trying to put a breakpoint through the webbrowser such as chrome. So adding it through changing the code is not the solution Im looking for here.

I am also trying to add a breakpoint after each transform to see what the result of the transformation is.

**Edit 2:**

I have tested both chrome debugger and also vscodes own debugger. They actually let you put breakpoints inside the transform function. They DO NOT allow you to set breakpoints after each transform function though (which I think is the most useful case).

Comment: Wouldn't one add breakpoints within the functions rather than at every step?

Comment: `debugger;` use this keyword just above where you want to start debugging and make use of step-in, step-out.

Comment: You can still put breakpoints on each call in the pipeline (at least in Chrome) and "step over" will stop at each `filter`, `sort`, `map`, `reduce` etc. (even if you've formatted the statement on a single line) - remember at any point you can also "step into".

Comment: @Emissary This does not work for me (chrome v59). Heard that it may be possible with canary though.

Comment: @ftor. Im not sure about the solution here. Maybe I should make it more clear. What Im trying to simulate is setting breakpoints after each transformation and not inside the function body. I would like to see the results after each step

Comment: I see. You used improper tags. Your question is unrelated to FP. Please replace _functional-programming_ with something like chrome dev tools.

Comment: I'm curious to know if you found a good approach to your request? if you did, share it. it might come handy to all of us someday.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tested both chrome debugger and also vscodes own debugger. They actually let you put breakpoints inside the transform function. They DO NOT allow you to set breakpoints after each transform function though (which I think is the most useful case). @taha

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend the Array prototype with a custom function:

```
Array.prototype.myDebugFn = function(){ 
 debugger;
 return this;
}
```

then you can chain **.myDebugFn()** whenever needed :

```
myArray
  .filter(fooFilter)
  .sort(fooSort)
  .myDebugFn()
  .map(fooMap)
  .reduce(fooReduce)
```

ps: in general, it's a bad idea to modify/extend the built-in object prototypes

Comment: Hopefully the OP won't forget to remove it from the prototype again.